# terminate wordpress redirecting

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I was running a blog on a server and I've moved it to a new server. I tried to visit the old site by using the IP address like ***.***.**.***/blog and I was redirected to the new site. I haven't found any line related to this issue in the .htaccess file. How can I visit the former blog by using IP? Here's the .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: please check in the plugin directory via ftp, may be you redirected the website with some plugin.

Comment: Thanks! I just checked the dir but found no suspicious plugin...
akismet bp-template-pack buddypress buddypress-toolbar conditional-custom-fields-shortcode custom-fields-shortcode dynamic-widgets facebook-page-publish flshow github google-analytics-for-wordpress hello.php index.php livejournal-importer manifest_v1.1 mimetypes-link-icons outbrain processingjs really-simple-facebook-twitter-share-buttons siteground-4 siteground-wp71 syntaxhighlighter syntax-highlighter-and-code-prettifier the-events-calendar visitor-maps wpcat2tag-importer wp-cumulus wp-sns-share wp-sticky wp-syntax wp-tsina

Comment: And also I deleted all the plugins but the situation doesn't turn any better. Btw, I can log in the old forum by visiting <IP>/phpbb

Comment: can you check for redirection code in index.php, what I think is your browser is getting to the old site but your old site is redirecting the browser to new website and your .htaccess is clean therefore the code must be there in plugin or index.php

Comment: I found it maybe...in the wp-config.php file:
    $base = '/blog/';
    define( 'DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'XXXXXXXXXX' ); //XXX is the site
    define( 'PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/blog/' );

but now the 'Error establishing a database connection' problem occurs... I'm sure the database name, username, password, and host are all correct... sigh

Comment: can you place the image of code in wp-config.php